# SQL Azure Always Encrypted column - how to change column's size when encrypted?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

I have a SQL Azure Db with Always Encrypted column (with Key Vault) which is VARCHAR(6) and now business required to change its size. How can I do this? I haven't found anything in the docs or anywhere else.

One thought would be to decrypt the column and encrypt it again. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible and really easy:

```
ALTER TABLE [LOGS].[SOMETABLE]
    ALTER COLUMN
    [CARDNUM] [varchar](19) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
GO
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Get the following error:Operand type clash: varchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar(20) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'

Comment: @devC I also got same error.  Do you remember how you resolved the issue?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but if we want to change the size of an encrypted column, it needs to be dropped and recreated. I havent found another solution yet.